# Chrome Canvas: Small globalAlpha ignored

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

On Chromium 90.0.4430.93 (which uses the same rendering engine as Chrome), the following fading effect does not work. Why? And how would one fix it?

It is done by painting over the canvas with another black canvas and a low `globalAlpha` on each `requestAnimationFrame` call.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let start;
let lastTime;

function draw() {
    canvas.bgcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.bgcanvas.width = canvas.width;
    canvas.bgcanvas.height = canvas.height;
    
    bgctx = canvas.bgcanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    bgctx.fillStyle   = '#000';
    bgctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function step(timestamp) {
    if (start === undefined)
        start = timestamp;
        lastTime = timestamp;
        
    const elapsed = timestamp - lastTime;
    lastTime = timestamp;

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.0001*elapsed;
    ctx.drawImage(canvas.bgcanvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    
    var x = (timestamp - start)*0.01 % 200;
    var y = 0;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#77f';
    ctx.arc(x, canvas.height/2-y, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    lines = [];
    
    draw();
    ctx.drawImage(canvas.bgcanvas, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
resizeCanvas();
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */

body {
    width:100%; height:100%;
}

canvas {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Result in Firefox:

[image]

Result in Chromium:
[image]

Comment: Alpha is a 8bit Uint value. The smallest theoretical global alpha value is ~1/255. If you include pre multiplied alpha and that alpha blending is a scalar applied to 8bit ints the smallest practical alpha is > 4 /255. You are using ~ 0.0001 * 16 which is way to small. It is firefox that is at fault not Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Blindman67's comment, I now understand that it is non-trivial to get the same exponential decay shown in the above figure. But a linear one that works browser independently is relatively simple: Just subtract `#010101` on each rendering step via the following code:

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
ctx.fillStyle   = '#010101';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

To change the speed of decay, one can e.g. only apply this effect every i-th iteration.

Since I needed this fade with a background that is not pure black, but has other content, I created a luminosity mask on a new canvas (`contentcanvas`) that I then applied to the background. Here is an example showcasing the full solution:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let start;
let lastTime;

let stepMod = 0;

function draw() {
    canvas.bgcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.bgcanvas.width = canvas.width;
    canvas.bgcanvas.height = canvas.height;
    
    bgctx = canvas.bgcanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    canvas.contentcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.contentcanvas.width = canvas.width;
    canvas.contentcanvas.height = canvas.height;
    
    canvas.contentctx = canvas.contentcanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    canvas.tmpcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.tmpcanvas.width = canvas.width;
    canvas.tmpcanvas.height = canvas.height;
    
    canvas.tmpctx = canvas.tmpcanvas.getContext('2d');
    
    bgctx.fillStyle   = '#000';
    bgctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        bgctx.font = "30px serif";
    bgctx.fillStyle   = '#ca3';
    bgctx.fillText("Hey!", 10, canvas.height/2+10);
}

function step(timestamp) {
    if (start === undefined)
        start = timestamp;
        lastTime = timestamp;
        
    const elapsed = timestamp - lastTime;
    lastTime = timestamp;
    
    if (stepMod == 1) {
        canvas.contentctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
        canvas.contentctx.fillStyle   = '#010101';
        canvas.contentctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        canvas.contentctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        stepMod = 0;
    }
    else {
        stepMod += 1;
    }
    
    var x = (timestamp - start)*0.01 % 200;
    var y = 0;
    
    canvas.contentctx.beginPath();
    canvas.contentctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    canvas.contentctx.arc(x, canvas.height/2-y, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    canvas.contentctx.closePath();
    canvas.contentctx.fill();
    
    canvas.tmpctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.tmpctx.drawImage(canvas.contentcanvas, 0, 0);
    canvas.tmpctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    canvas.tmpctx.fillStyle = '#77f';
    canvas.tmpctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.tmpctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle   = '#fff';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "difference";
    ctx.drawImage(canvas.contentcanvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    ctx.drawImage(canvas.bgcanvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    ctx.drawImage(canvas.tmpcanvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    lines = [];
    
    draw();
    ctx.drawImage(canvas.bgcanvas, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
resizeCanvas();
window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */

body {
    width:100%; height:100%;
}

canvas {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```